# Finding all the JAR packages that are installed in a system for vulnerability scanning

Tags: java, security, jar, crlf-vulnerability

I'm trying to find and list all the Java Jar files in the system for vulnerability scanning.

Need to get the information regarding their version and any active CVEs that are against those Versions of JAR.

Will also appreciate any advice on tools that can do it.

tried listing all the Jar files manually, but couldnt get the version info from that.

Comment: Finding all installed JAR files can be done using an OS-specific command; e.g. `sudo find / -name \*.jar`.  The duplink tells you how to find a JAR's version information (if any) ... in addition to what is implied by the JAR file's filename.

Comment: ...and for the CVEs you can use https://owasp.org/www-project-dependency-check/